# ¿Cómo ejecutar la función asociada a un evento? Me está mostrando el texto con su código

Tags: javascript

```js
function lol() {
   var b = new Cell();
   document.write(b.clan);
}

  
function Cell(){
  this.clan = function() {
  this.b = document.getElementById("clan").value;
  return this.b();
 };  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="clan"/>
  <input type="button" onclick="lol()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

¿Por qué, al apretar el botón, esta función me muestra el cuerpo del método (su código) y no su contenido, no la ejecuta? ¿y cómo lo soluciono?

Comment: Da un poco mas de detalles sobre tu pregunta

Comment: Al apretar el boton, me muestra al cuerpo del método y no su contenido en sí.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente tienes 2 erroes el primero es `document.write(b.clan);` debe ser 
`document.write(b.clan());` y return `this.b();` debe ser `return this.b;`

```js
function lol() {
   var b = new Cell();
   document.write(b.clan());
}

  
function Cell(){
  this.clan = function() {
  this.b = document.getElementById("clan").value;
  return this.b;
  };  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="clan"/>
  <input type="button" onclick="lol()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Wilfredo !!

Comment: @EduardoSebastian De nada, recuerda aceptar la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Fácil... lo que ocurre es que en esta linea `document.write(b.clan);` estas llamando una función, sin ponerle los `()`

Osea, quedaría, así:

```
document.write(b.clan());
```

Y para que no te retorne un error. debes quitar los parentesis de `b`, quedando así:

```
...
return this.b;
```

Comment: Y, en el `return`, sobran los paréntesis porque `b` no es una función.

Comment: gracias @SJuan76, ya lo edité